# Как убрать отступы нижним блокам и при этом сделать оступы между блоками

Tags: css, html5

Допустим есть четыре div блока, и мы задаем им display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;, четыре блока по 200px как между ними сделать равные отступы и при этом что бы у нижних двух не было отступов снизу, а только у первых двух

Answer (score 2):

Я нашел ответ, существует два метода, через метод gap или через псевдокласс nth-child(n). gap убирает лишние отступы нижним или правым краиним элементам создавая отступы только (внутри) элементов и делая хороший адаптив. в случае nth-child можно прописать что div:not(nth-last-child(-n+2){margin-bottom: 10px} и тогда мы будем всегда убирать отступы нижним элементам и при этом адаптив сохраняется при добавлений элементов

Comment: Хорошо что вы ответ рашли самостоятельно, но всё же лучше в свой ответ прикладывать весь код..

Comment: извиняюсь, как-то не подумал